# How to run the equivalent of mvn install:install-file before compilation

Tags: java, maven

How to run the equivalent of `mvn install:install-file` before the compilation phase. We have a file under `lib/foo-1.0.0.jar` which is not present in a Maven repo. So we install it manually using mvn install:install-file and put this as a dependency during the compile phase. But if the file is not installed in your local repository, it fails with a compilation error. How do I instruct maven to install this automatically prior to compilation

Comment: Install this file from were? This jar is saved in your project under version control?

Comment: Yes its under version control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use system dependency scope

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.company.groupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/foo-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

`${basedir}` - is dir of your `pom.xml`
**EDIT**
also you can use `build-helper-maven-plugin`

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifacts>
                <artifact>
                  <file>${basedir}/lib/foo-1.0.0.jar</file>
                  <type>jar</type>
                  <classifier>optional</classifier>
                </artifact>
              </artifacts>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: This will work, but it's quite an unusual thing to do. Usually it's best to stick to the one-artifact-per-module convention. Setting up a Nexus repo is really easy.

Comment: @artbristol setting up a nexus repository adds complexity to the setup.  This approach allows anybody to checkout the project and run "mvn clean install" without having to read instructions first.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I agree, being able to mvn clean install without faffing is really important. Could you specify the nexus repo in the `repositories` section of the pom?

Answer (score 2):

Install a company-wide Maven proxy such as Nexus, and put the artifact there. Each developer needs to alter their `settings.xml` to point to that proxy. Checking jars into version control is generally a bad idea, especially if you want to move to a distributed SCM.